# Locating land title technical description on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, land-survey

I am planning to buy a certain property but I'm too far away from where it's located to check it personally.

The seller sends me a technical description of the property and I'm trying to locate it on google maps. he also said its somewhere around here [https://www.google.com/maps/place/7%C2%B047'47.1%22N+126%C2%B001'40.9%22E/@7.7964283,126.0258283,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m2!2m1!1s-91.2525!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d7.7964231!4d126.0280167](https://www.google.com/maps/place/7%C2%B047%2747.1%22N+126%C2%B001%2740.9%22E/@7.7964283,126.0258283,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m9!1m2!2m1!1s-91.2525!3m5!1s0x0:0x0!7e2!8m2!3d7.7964231!4d126.0280167)

Unfortunately, I do not know how to decode the technical description to convert into latitude and longitude coordinates that I can use to locate it on Google Maps and I'm not even sure if its possible.

Can anybody advise if the details on the image below can be used on locating the area on Google Maps and if there's any tools or formula I can use.

[image]

Comment: This is more an issue for a professional (licensed and bonded) surveyor. You really want to get this right (or have someone to sue if it was done wrong), so do-it-yourself is not the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks for your response. but its not like Im using the map for legal purposes. I only wanted to check it on google maps/earth to know some details like the shape of the area, how far is it from the road, its landscape etc. it doesn't need to be 100% accurate

Comment: what appears above the portion of the survey that you included above? That's where I'd look for a description of the starting point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not quite possible with the information you have provided.

The main thing missing is how to locate the "point of beginning", from which the text you provide locates the remaining points, which lie in a hexagon that is nearly a rectangle approx 350x100m+- lying roughly to that "point of beginning's" northwest.

As an example, the first line says point 2 lies 375.93 metres in the direction S 85deg 48 W, which is a bearing 4.5 degrees to the south of directly due west. For more on interpreting these instructions, see https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog160/node/1926

Actually, to do this completely right, you would have to understand details about what grid the bearings are relative to -- see https://www.flatironsinc.com/services/learn/bearings.php -- but this is likely immaterial in your situation.

*If* you could pinpoint the "point of beginning", for instance by its latitude and longitude, then you could use a GIS program like QGIS, or even manual/spreadsheet calculations if you're not scared of trigonometry, to convert those bearings and distances to create a KML file that you could then display on Google Maps (or alternately show Google Maps or another map source in that same GIS program).

If you can pinpoint one of the other boundary points, you can also reverse engineer the hexagon from that other starting point. But unless you have Longitude/Latitude or other (e.g. UTM,...) coordinates for at least one of those points, you don't have enough to go by.

Comment: Adding: you can technically follow this approach using the "somewhere here" location you provided as the "point of beginning". But it feels too vague to be trustworthy. I opened the link and see no immediately obvious satellite-visible features that would have clearly the right shape and size right at that point.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your clarification, and yeah, I pretty much suspect the main issue would be to locate any of the starting point, anyway, its good to know its almost rectangular though, if only seller knows how to locate stuff on google maps, would have been easier for me to locate it

Answer (score 0):

I am referencing & adding to [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/385633/107424).

So, "houska" provided a very comprehensive answer here that deserves kudos for it's comprehensibility, complete-ness, and for the fact that the writer respects the reader enough to write without over-simplification while also avoiding excessive use of technical jargon or industry-specific verbiage. It is rare that such a balanced answer is offered to questions like this on virtually every platform, and the fact that it is the first answer makes it further worthy of appreciation...

But, as is mentioned in a comment above, there *is* geographic data adequate to serve as the reference point; "point of beginning"... Though it is not explicitly stated as such, you could assume it is *likely* the "point of beginning", but it is *very likely* within the boundaries defined, and *almost certainly* relatively proximal to the plot in question.

By "relatively proximal", I mean that, to someone familiar with the property roughly as aware as a typical owner whose not residing on the property, but represents the level of familiarity you would expect from someone having acquired the property as an investment, or for use in a hobby like hunting, micro-agriculture, botany, gardening, or boutique commercial flower cultivation...

The point should be as near the property as is easily identified without the use of surveying equipment, utilizing landmarks the individual associates with their property lines - the more inconsequential & unremarkable the distinction between one & another side of the property, the less apparent that property line will be. Assuming you are dealing with someone acting in good faith & capable of reasonably well-executed & estimated assumptions, this map & the survey data defining the boundary lines relative a starting point in the post can be used to produce a hypothetical plot which is likely to deviate from the legal boundaries such that the descrepancy (if any) is effectively immaterial...

So, you should be able to reasonably assume that the plot shape & size super-imposed upon the link's map starting from that geographical point will provide a representation of the property that is accurate *in spirit*; you should be able to use that deduced interpretation as adequate for assessing the qualitative state, features, flora, soils, slope, etc of the property.

If you follow the link and look at the area around the point, the above deduction seems further strengthened by the surrounding buildings & their positions relative the plotted point (forming a semi-hexagonal relative shape if logical property lines are assumed onto the map, and the street is used as one of the boundaries, it matches roughly the shape qualitatively (**at a quick glance at the table of measures regarding the boundaries & a brief look at a couple layers of the map the link leads to**).

Further, from the sat layer, within that region, the distinguishability from one possible boundary location to another results in little consequence in terms of the lay of the land assuming there aren't buildings on the property.

When looking at the the default view illustrating manmade structures/roads, the property lines seem even more confidently deducible... in fact, if I were to spend more time on this - adequate to determine the lengths & directions or angles of the boundaries described versus the length & angle of that section of roadway, you would almost certainly find that the property has a boundary which follows that road running along the south-east corner of the patch of land between the surrounding buildings immediately near that map's plotted point...

I am sorry that this is so long, but I am sure that you can deduce property boundaries using the information here - the point of beginning is probably the furthest south or north of that road which doesn't impose on the neighboring buildings, and which allows for one of the boundary sections to fit... like, one of those resulting lines running northeast to southwest (or vice-versa), should fit nicely with that section of road. That is how you will find the point of beginning with a very high degree of confidence...

Comment: 2nd glance, road=pt 3-4; one line follows the road, then before that first building southwest of the section of road, the boundary goes near due-west shortly, then near due north for the longest boundary line, extending past all of the buildings surrounding the plotted point, then if we start from point 4 (other end of road boundary), go almost due north, then combine those long lines using a near E-W line (really 2 segments with a very slight vertices 13m & 57m from the points terminating the long N-S boundaries that extend from near the road & between the buildings visible on the map. ;p

Answer (score 0):

I came across this exact problem. Turns out I just need the coordinates of the reference point used by the surveyor, which is also included in the Technical Description

Just in case you're still interested, kindly include the rest of the Technical Description above the bearings that you posted and I might be able to help in plotting. There's a bunch of GPS coordinates being passed around by local surveyors